# pyramid of asterisks in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

1

I should do this exercise in 8086 assembly

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

but as output I get only the first asterisk. where is the problem?

they told me to use pop and push but not having studied them, I do not know how to do it. I hope someone will give me a valid help to solve this code. Also I'm doing the code on dosbox this is my code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK
.DATA
nl db 0dh,0ah, '$'
. CODE
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov cx,5
mov bx,1

for1: 
push cx
mov dl,20h
mov ah,2
for2:
int 21h
loop for2
mov cx,bx
mov dl,'*'
mov ah,2
for3:
int 21h
loop for3
lea dx,nl
mov ah,9
int 21h
inc bx
inc dx
inc cx

loop for1

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

END
```

it is a school problem we are developing with the TASM and we have not yet studied complicated instructions but only those used in the code made by me.
Can someone correct it?

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Also make sure you know how `loop` instruction works - you have `inc cx` which hints you use it wrong. You also have unbalanced `push cx`. Learn to use a debugger (turbo debugger is a nice one you should have available).

Comment: Homework problems are generally not answered here

Comment: @GabrielFair That's generally wrong, homework questions _are_ answered here, but they must follow SO guidelines. For example, posts containing assignment texts only without context, research and effort are closed.

Comment: ok, great then. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> where is the problem?

You're using the `CX` register wrong in several ways.

Looking at the desired pyramid you find:

```
     *       5 leading spaces and 1 asterisk
    ***      4 leading spaces and 3 asterisks
   *****     3 leading spaces and 5 asterisks
  *******    2 leading spaces and 7 asterisks
 *********   1 leading space  and 9 asterisks
```

What your code already tries to do is keep a running count of asterisks in the `BX` register. Once you correct the typo `inc dx` and change it into `inc bx`, this will be fine.

When it comes to controlling the amount of leading spaces, your choice for the `CX` register complicates matters to the point that your program gets stuck.
You should choose an extra register for this purpose. I suggest selecting `BP`.

```
    mov     bp, 5       ; first line has 5 spaces
    mov     bx, 1       ; first line has 1 asterisk
next: 

    mov     cx, bp      ; current number of spaces
spaces:
    mov     dl, " "
    mov     ah, 02h
    int     21h
    loop    spaces

    mov     cx, bx      ; current number of asterisks
asterisks:
    mov     dl, "*"
    mov     ah, 02h
    int     21h
    loop    asterisks

    lea     dx, nl
    mov     ah, 09h
    int     21h

    add     bx, 2       ; 2 asterisks more each line
    dec     bp          ; 1 space less each line
    jnz     next        ; until no more leading space needed
```

If for some reason you don't want the bottom line prefixed with a single space, next version does just that:

```
    mov     bp, 4       ; first line has 4 spaces
    mov     bx, 1       ; first line has 1 asterisk
next: 

    mov     cx, bp      ; current number of spaces
    jcxz    NoSpaces
spaces:
    mov     dl, " "
    mov     ah, 02h
    int     21h
    loop    spaces
NoSpaces:

    ...

    add     bx, 2       ; 2 asterisks more each line
    dec     bp          ; 1 space less each line
    jns     next        ; until no more leading space needed
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. finally it works.
If instead I wanted to insert the number of asterisks in the base in the input user, how should I proceed?
Type here are 9 asterisks at the base and the user would like 15 or 21, at his choice.
Is there a way to do it?